# If TCP/IP header counts 40 bytes, 8 bytes of WebSocket message actually gets > 40 bytes?

Tags: networking, websocket, tcp

I'm thinking about how to reduce the total data transfer size of WebSocket.

From my understanding, WebSocket header has only 2 bytes at minimum. So I first thought that if the message payload has 8 bytes for example, sending this message is like `[payload] + [websocket header] = 8 + 2 = 10` bytes of data transfer in total.

However, if I think about it, TCP header has minimum length of 20 bytes and so does the IP[V4] header. Also variable(?) ethernet header `α` bytes depending on hardware and protocol is added.

Does this mean that sending 98 bytes of message once (= `[payload] + [websocket header] + [ip header] + [tcp header] + [ethernet header] = 98 + 2 + 20 + 20 + α > 140` bytes) is generally better than sending 8 bytes of data five times (= `([payload] + [websocket header] + [ip header] + [tcp header] + [ethernet header]) * 5 = (8 + 2 + 20 + 20 + α) * 5 > 250` bytes) ?

Comment: Not sure what kind of answer you're looking for? Yes, sending fewer bytes generally is better. That's why algorithms like Nagle exist. But if you're building a chat application, you'd better not wait until the user has entered 98 (or whatever arbitrary cutoff point you choose) characters, because then their last message(s) might never be sent.

Comment: Given the overhead, you should be thinking about how to *increase* it really.

Comment: @CodeCaster Ah, Nagle. That's what I was looking for!

Comment: No, it's not like you want to implement Nagle yourself, or implement something like it for websockets...

Comment: @CodeCaster Year, I know I know. I learned about it long time ago but it was completely slipped out of my memory. Also I have checked its relationship with websocket and it seems that basically tcp_nodelay, *un-*nagle, is enabled everywhere using websocket? It might be the case I should manually enable it if bandwodth is my concern.